# Getting item with child conditions

Tags: mysql

My table looks like this

[image]

I need to get an item (product) which has child items that have an upcoming date. In the example's case, item 3 has 2 children that only one of them (item 5) has an upcoming date. Which means, I only want to get item 3 and others like it.

Can anyone help me create a query for that?

EDIT:

The answers are really helpful and did get some of the job done. I'm trying to temper with existing query, any thoughts on where or how to do that?

```
p.`virtuemart_product_id` FROM `#__virtuemart_products` as p LEFT JOIN
`#__virtuemart_product_shoppergroups` as ps ON
p.`virtuemart_product_id` = `ps`.`virtuemart_product_id` LEFT JOIN
`#__virtuemart_product_categories` as pc ON
p.`virtuemart_product_id` = `pc`.`virtuemart_product_id` WHERE
( ((p.`product_parent_id` = "0" AND `pc`.`virtuemart_category_id` > "0")
OR p.`product_parent_id` > "0") AND ((p.`product_parent_id` > "0"
AND `pc`.`virtuemart_category_id` > "0") OR p.`product_parent_id` = "0")
AND ( `ps`.`virtuemart_shoppergroup_id`= "1" OR
`ps`.`virtuemart_shoppergroup_id` IS NULL ) AND p.`published`="1" )
group by p.`virtuemart_product_id` ORDER BY `pc`.`ordering` ASC,
`virtuemart_product_id` ASC
```

Comment: How deeply can the products be nested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `self` join.

```
SELECT t.id 
FROM YourTable t, YourTable s
WHERE t.id = s.parent_id
AND s.date > NOW();
```